My Bitbucket pipeline fails on the CodeDeploy step (deploying to EC2 instance)
AWS newbie here.
I'm working on my first Bitbucket pipeline to deploy to AWS. It has three steps:

Zip up the project files
Upload to an AWS S3 Bucket
Use CodeDeploy to deploy the application files to the EC2 instance

Here's my most recent run:

Actually, I consider this making progress! The first time I ran this, I stopped this myself around the 6 and a half minute mark as it appeared to be hung on this line:
aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id d-V1OU4NNG8

This time it failed on its own, giving at least some diagnostic information to look at.
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/aws-code-deploy:0.2.10
INFO: Deploying app from revision.
aws deploy get-application-revision --application-name lightning-comm --revision revisionType=S3,s3Location={bucket=lightning-comm-codedeploy-deployment,bundleType=zip,key=lightning-comm-10-b614e62f}
{
    "applicationName": "lightning-comm", 
    "revisionInfo": {
        "lastUsedTime": 1726775747.124, 
        "firstUsedTime": 1726775747.124, 
        "registerTime": 1726775712.153, 
        "description": "Application revision registered by Deployment ID: d-K49RJELG8", 
        "deploymentGroups": []
    }, 
    "revision": {
        "revisionType": "S3", 
        "s3Location": {
            "bundleType": "zip", 
            "bucket": "lightning-comm-codedeploy-deployment", 
            "key": "lightning-comm-10-b614e62f"
        }
    }
}
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name lightning-comm --deployment-group deployment --revision revisionType=S3,s3Location={bucket=lightning-comm-codedeploy-deployment,bundleType=zip,key=lightning-comm-10-b614e62f} --ignore-application-stop-failures --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE
{
    "deploymentId": "d-V1OU4NNG8"
}
INFO: Deployment created with id d-V1OU4NNG8.
INFO: Waiting for deployment to complete.
aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id d-V1OU4NNG8
Waiter DeploymentSuccessful failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state
ERROR: Deployment failed. Fetching deployment information...
aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id d-V1OU4NNG8
{
    "deploymentInfo": {
        "applicationName": "lightning-comm", 
        "status": "Failed", 
        "deploymentOverview": {
            "Skipped": 0, 
            "Succeeded": 0, 
            "Failed": 1, 
            "Ready": 0, 
            "InProgress": 0, 
            "Pending": 0
        }, 
        "computePlatform": "Server", 
        "deploymentConfigName": "CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce", 
        "creator": "user", 
        "errorInformation": {
            "message": "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.", 
            "code": "HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS"
        }, 
        "fileExistsBehavior": "OVERWRITE", 
        "deploymentId": "d-V1OU4NNG8", 
        "deploymentStatusMessages": [], 
        "ignoreApplicationStopFailures": true, 
        "deploymentStyle": {
            "deploymentType": "IN_PLACE", 
            "deploymentOption": "WITHOUT_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
        }, 
        "updateOutdatedInstancesOnly": false, 
        "rollbackInfo": {}, 
        "instanceTerminationWaitTimeStarted": false, 
        "deploymentGroupName": "deployment", 
        "createTime": 1726780175.753, 
        "completeTime": 1726780481.716, 
        "revision": {
            "revisionType": "S3", 
            "s3Location": {
                "bundleType": "zip", 
                "bucket": "lightning-comm-codedeploy-deployment", 
                "key": "lightning-comm-10-b614e62f"
            }
        }
    }
}

This appears to be the relevant info:
        "errorInformation": {
            "message": "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.", 
            "code": "HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS"
        }

OK, "too many individual instances failed", "too few healthy instances" - I'm only deploying to a single EC2 instance and that one is failing. Whatever is wrong, it's not failing very quickly, it takes about 5+ minutes to fail. I imagine that whatever is wrong, or if there are additional diagnostics to be examined, those are going to be found over on the AWS side. I'm a complete newbie at AWS. If you can give me some guidance for what to look for on the AWS side to either find additional diagnostics, or where to find a possible misconfiguration, that will be very helpful. Thanks!

I figured it out. I was missing the file appspec.yml at the root of my deployment folder structure.
I added this appspec.yml (it's bare-bones, I'm taking this step by step):
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /api
hooks:

Success!

AppSpec is defined here if you'd like more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-ecs
